# Cookie is not stored after refresh .net mvc

Tags: c#, cookies

I am testing something quick, but I can't save cookies into browser. When I check cookies in browser they are not there. My code:

```
private void WriteCookie(string setting, string settingValue)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(setting);
            // Set the cookie value.
            myCookie.Value = settingValue;
            // Set the cookie expiration date.
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

            // Add the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
        }

        private string ReadCookie(string setting)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(setting);
            myCookie = Request.Cookies[setting];

            // Read the cookie information and display it.
            if (myCookie != null)
                return myCookie.Value;

            return null;
        }
```

I am setting cookie in MVC action #1:

```
    if(page != null)
    {
        WriteCookie("page", page.ToString());
    }

    if (pageDraft != null)
    {
        WriteCookie("pageDraft", pageDraft.ToString());
    }
```

Then I read:

```
    if (ReadCookie("page") != null)
        page = Convert.ToInt32(ReadCookie("page"));

    if (ReadCookie("pageDraft") != null)
        pageDraft = Convert.ToInt32(ReadCookie("pageDraft"));
```

When page is refreshed, I lose cookies. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Probslem was web.config:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

Changed to:

```
<httpCookies  httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```